# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID error: 80070005 Access is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

I am trying to use my asp.net application to open the outlook. It is working fine on my machine. now i am deploying the app to the server. i got this exception

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
```

I have been trying to solve this exception for three days. i googled a lot.

#### What I tried

they said that i have to go to `DCOM CONFIG`, i went there but I didn't find the microsoft office outlook entry.

then i opened a cmd and I typed `mcc -32` and then i added the component server. **after that** i saw the outlook entry. i went to the property and then to the security tab, then i change the three of the options there to give access to the **everyone** user. but i kept having this problem

**Note** that I did that changes to these two entries

```
Microsoft Outlook Commadn Button

outlook message attachment
```

then i changed the user of the application bool to the `Administrator` account of the server, but i kept having the problem

please help me, i tried a lot really a lot to solve , but i couldn't

Comment: What user is the ASP.NET  worker process running under? It is possible that that user doesn't have access to the outlook inbox you're trying to access.

Comment: @simonatrcl for some reason, i don't know what happened, that error gone, and i got this new error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537934/c-sharp-asp-net-timeout-when-calling-a-outlook-email could you help please

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to use my asp.net application to open the outlook.

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

As a workaround you can use the low-level API - Extended MAPI. Or any other third-party wrappers around that API (for example, Redemption).

Comment: you copied the answer of this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/819b9871-a435-4d85-aefd-fccd9d28094f/httpexception-0x80004005-request-timed-out-at-windows-server-2012?forum=worddev i had already checked it

Comment: This is a standard answer for such questions.