# c# asp.net timeout when calling a outlook email

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, outlook, office-interop

> My requirement is that i need to develop a web app , (it is mandatory
>   to be a web app).
>   This app lists the outlook templates that has been
>   saved in a specific directly.
>   Beside each template, there is a load
>   button, you can say a load link if you want
>   When the agent (client)
>   clicks it, the outlook should open with that template.

I am trying to open the outlook from my asp.net application. when i click on my button, i execute this code

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem oMailItem2 = oApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(templateFilePath);
oMailItem2.Display(true);
```

It is working on my machine, but when i deploy it on the server, i got this error:

```
Request timed out.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out.]

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929
```

It seems a very general error, what could be the problem please? how can I diagnosis it?

#### Note

The body of the message in my case must be a html, not text. that is why i am not able to `mailto` like this

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?subject=This%20is%20the%20subject&cc=someone_else@example.com&body=This%20is%20the%20body">Send email</a>
```

Comment: Post the stack trace, as the message suggests.

Comment: @simonatrcl i give you all the error message

Comment: @simonatrcl i updated my quesiton, could you check please

Comment: Ugh - I hate email in applications. I've found problems like this are a royal pain to debug and troubleshoot. If this is intermittent, your code is probably fine. Is your email timing out? Are you sending 1 or 1+ messages at once? Check for a valid outbound address and a good connection to your relay.

Comment: Ok Marco, you want to use this way of coding also if it is not recommended. Can you tell me why? Have you ever tried SmtpClient?

Comment: @Tim i am requesting to open the outlook just one time, with one message, i am loading that message from a folder that is in the server, that is it, how can i know the error please? i just get time out error

Comment: I wish I knew - a timeout could be caused by any number of things. The only thing I can recommend is send the email asynchronously with .NET code instead of Outlook (as mentioned in the answer below) and don't wait for it to return. If you can, break messaging out into a service or scheduled task with a longer timeout.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli , I'm not sure if I understand correctly: you are trying to open an Outlook window on the server desktop from your asp.net application? When you tested locally you were testing on local IIS or IIS Express?

Comment: @lowleveldesign i am trying to open the outlook on the client machine (in my case, the client is an agent in the same domain). now i did everything i know so i deployed the app on  the client machine (just as a test) and it is still giving me the time out error .please help

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli but still the code you pasted is from an ASP.NET application? The client machine runs IIS and Outlook at the same time, am I right? Are you using IIS Express or full-featured IIS?

Comment: @lowleveldesign the client machine has iis and outlook and for my development machine it is IIS that comes with visual studio

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli  "i am trying to open the outlook on the client machine" this is not possible! Your code invoking Office via Office.Interop and COM+ is executed in the server, by IIS that is serving your application!!!

Comment: @EmanueleGreco it seems you are write, now i am able to open the outlook just on the server, not in the client, what should i do please in order to open the outlook in the client? my requirement is an html body for the message. otherwise, i would have used <a> tag malito option

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli So, definitely, let's try to solve your problem. Type your scenario and objective (not the way you are trying to do it) and let's look for the easyest way to achieve it.

Comment: @EmanueleGreco my requirement is that i need to develop a **web app** , it is mandatory to be a web app. this app **lists** the outlook templates that has been saved in a specific directly. Beside each template, there is a load button, you can say a load link if you want, when the agent (client) clicks it, the outlook should open with that template. is it clear please?

Comment: Ok, very clear. I Added this scenario into the question.

Comment: @EmanueleGreco thank you, i really hope someone helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75093/discussion-between-emanuele-greco-and-marco-dinatsoli).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a .msg file on the server, and you want to edit it and transmit it to users.

**1) edit your template**

https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23+edit+.msg+file

there are many 3rd party tools that can help to edit a .msg files
**2. Send it to the user**

```
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path)) 
{ 
int length = (int)fs.Length; 
byte[] buffer; 

using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs)) 
{ 
buffer = br.ReadBytes(length); 
} 

Response.Clear(); 
Response.Buffer = true; 
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}", Path.GetFileName(path))); 
Response.ContentType = "application/" + Path.GetExtension(path).Substring(1); 
Response.BinaryWrite(buffer); 
Response.End() 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts to help me. i know that i can open a text/plain, but the requirement is pretty sticky here. the manager needs html body. and i am in risk.

Answer (score 2):

Marco, as I already wrote to you at [Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID error: 80070005 Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29536161/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-error-80070005-access/29537511?noredirect=1#comment47227937_29537511)

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

As a workaround you can use the low-level API - Extended MAPI. Or any other third-party wrappers around that API (for example, Redemption).

Comment: you can't keep posting the same answer, this is an answer not connect to my question at all. you have already posted it there and i told you that you have copied it and i didn't downvote that answer, but now i downvoted your answer, please delete it

Comment: you are keep saying that Microsoft is not suggesting this way of coding. Okay, but i want to use this way of programming, and i got a problem, you can't keep me to not using this way of programming .

Comment: That way is not supported. You need to use Extended MAPI. Nobody will be able to help you in that case. The answer will be the same.

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to use Outlook in a server? Have you looked into using EWS or an Extended MAPI rapper (Redemption)?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko this is the requirement, we need to have a button, and when the client (here the client is an agent inside the domain) clicks that button, the outlook should open

Comment: How can Outlook open on the *client* if your code is running on the *server*? mailto url is the best you can do. You can create local COM objects (Outlook.Application) from JavaScript only when running inside IE if the site is trusted.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're falling into this problem: have you ever tried logging into your Pc  as Marco, and then setting up Outlook with your account. 
Then, if you log as a different user, Outlook must be properly configured with his email account.
**Actually, when IIS launches you asp.net application, it is living into a "no user" session, and no set is available for Outlook.**
Maybe, your debug program worked because it was launched into a normal "Marco" session.

## Possible solution

1. **Create a real User** (i.e. "Server Admin"), login with that user into
   the server, and **configure Outlook**
2. Open IIS, take the Application Pool of your application, chooes "Advanced settings" and then **set "Application pool identity" to a "Custom account"**.

I hope this is enough to make your program work.

Comment: OK, I'm waiting for your feedback. Anyway, if the same task can be achieved via SmtpClient it could be easier

Comment: I did all what you said, and I kept having the same exception. i am really out of my mind, it is the end of the day here. we continue tomorrow (maybe tomorrow i have a meeting), then Saturday we continue

Comment: please help ,  i am still having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem here is that you are trying to mix client and server logic in one application. Opening an Outlook window from an ASP.NET application server side is a very bad idea - IIS application pools are not allowed to interact with a user desktop (starting from Windows Vista or Windows Server 2008 they run in Session 0 which does not have a visible desktop available). So the Outlook window opens, but no one will ever see it. I assume that if it's a modal window it blocks the parent thread causing the timeout, but I'm not sure as I haven't had a chance to check it. On your development machine you have an IIS Express instance which runs in the same session as the current user and that's why you can see the Outlook window. The request is probably hanging for the whole time you interact with the Outlook dialog.

I understand that you are under time pressure so the only recommendation I have for you for now is to install on your client machine IIS Express (you may get it from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34679) and run your application from it. BUT in the meantime rewrite this logic - either create a web form to allow the user to compose an email and then use `SmtpClient` class to send it for him or use [mailto url](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) that shoudl open Outlook window with valid data in it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will check the visibality to install iis express, but not i find something weird, i went to the outlook.exe and i grand full access to `iis-user` and `iuser` and `everyone` and `network service` , then i checked the task manager before running my web app, and outlook.exe wasn't there, then when i run my app, the outlook.exe becomes appears in the task manager and the error message now is `Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))`

Comment: and this is the whole stack 
Stack Trace: 


[COMException (0x80004004): Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))]
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass.CreateItemFromTemplate(String TemplatePath, Object InFolder) +0
   Popup.EmailTemplate.openOutlook(Object sender, EventArgs e) +501
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +155
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3804

Comment: COM doesn't provide enough details about the error; you should analyze system-application event log to know what's happening.